# Select tag in angular2 is not working

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I don't know what's wrong with the below code. But the select tag won't show the available options.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Select a Department"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment" required>
              <option *ngFor="let department of departments"
                [ngValue]="department">
                {{department.name}}
              </option>
  </select>
```

But the values are shown when accesing chrome developer tools.

```
<nb-select-department _ngcontent-umj-27="" _nghost-umj-28="" ng-reflect-departments="[object Object],[object Object]"><div class="btn-group bootstrap-select ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid open"><button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn btn-primary btn-round" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" title="Select a Department" aria-expanded="true"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Select a Department</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 86px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" style="max-height: 86px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"></ul></div><select _ngcontent-umj-28="" class="selectpicker ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" required="" title="Select a Department" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]" tabindex="-98"><option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select a Department</option>
              <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><option _ngcontent-umj-28="" value="0: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">
                Development
              </option><option _ngcontent-umj-28="" value="1: Object" ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]">
                Management
              </option>
            </select></div></nb-select-department>
```

`select-department.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nb-select-department',
  templateUrl: './select-department.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-department.component.css']
})
export class SelectDepartmentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() departments: any;
  @Output() done: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  selectedDepartment: any = {'name': 'Select A Department'};

  constructor() { }
}
```

`user-component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nb-user-form',
  templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-form.component.css']
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

...
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.user));
    this.buildForm();
    this.getDepartments();
  }

  getDepartments() {
    this.organisationService.listDepartments(this.user.userKey).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.departments = data.departments;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.departments)); 
        // [{"department_key":"ahVlfm5leHRib29raW5nLWJhY2tlbmRyMAsSDE9yZ2FuaXNhdGlvbhiAgICA-MKECgwLEgpEZXBhcnRtZW50GICAgICAgIAJDA","name":"Development"},{"department_key":"ahVlfm5leHRib29raW5nLWJhY2tlbmRyMAsSDE9yZ2FuaXNhdGlvbhiAgICA-MKECgwLEgpEZXBhcnRtZW50GICAgICAgIAKDA","name":"Management"}]
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`user-form-component.html`

```
<nb-select-department [departments]="departments" (done)="onSelectDeperatmentDone($event)"></nb-select-department>
```

Comment: You see, it properly displays the department values `Development`, `Management` but on clicking the dropdown list, it shows nothing..

Comment: Share your ts code please..

Comment: where is the values for departments?

Comment: @AJT_82 is the code related to getting departments is very important?

Comment: Well yes, since that seems to be the problem :)

Comment: Create a plunk on http://plnkr.co

Comment: @AJT_82 then I have show my whole project to you..

Comment: @AJT_82 updated.. Now you know how I pass data from parent to child..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well now we are starting to get enough information, thank you :)

Comment: I haven't seen any error report on console.log.. But the select list wasn't shown properly.

Comment: What does "wasn't shown properly" mean exactly? I'd expect it is either shown or not shown.

Comment: This is what I got https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZZ7K.png on clicking the dropdown button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since data coming async have you tried putting `*ngIf`:

```
<nb-select-department *ngIf="departments" [departments]="departments" (done)="onSelectDeperatmentDone($event)"></nb-select-department>
```

EDIT: Pass data back to the parent:

in your select-dropdown (child) you should have change-event, or as PO better suggested, `(ngModelChange)`:

```
(change)=emitDepartment(department)
```

in your child component:

```
@Output() done = new EventEmitter<Object>();

emitDepartment(department) {
   this.done.emit(department);
}
```

parent html stays the same, your parent component:

```
done(department) {
  //do whatever you want...
}
```

Comment: now I want the selected department from select-department component to user-form component. ie, On selecting a department `selectedDepartment` value gets updated.. Now I want to emit this value to parent component on change in selectedDepartment.

Comment: figured it through `(ngModelChange)="onChangeDepartment()"`

Comment: so this got trigged when anyone of the model variable got changed , right?

Comment: are you there? One small doubt.. As for now, the select box by default shows `Select A Department`. But I want to show the value of department if exists or the default `Select A dept` stmt. `selectedDepartment = {'name': department || 'Select A Department'}; ` where department comes from user-form component. On debugger, it properly shows the department value but the value on select box not get changed.